# Pymol: color spheres with different colors

Tags: pymol

Hello I am a Pymol user

I want to color all alpha carbons (ca) and beta carbons (cb) from a certain ressidue in different color. How can I do this?

I selected the spheres with:

```
show spheres, C/1-9/ca 
show spheres, C/1-9/cb
```

and if I use

```
set sphere_color, theColor
```

I color all the spheres what I don't want.

according to: `color    gold,    resi    200-­‐221`
I tried
`gold,    spheres, C/1-9/ca`
but this didn't work

Comment: Hi @Elias whilst your question is certainly answerable it is etiquette to provide a few more details about your investigation. Past posts do answer this specific question

Answer (score 1):

### Spheres

So how PyMOL stores how it shows atoms is that each atom has a colour and a represention, which is a binary number telling what to show. Therefore the colour for `spheres` is the same as the colour for `sticks`. The only way round this is to copy the object (`create copycat, original` and you set copycat differently)

To set the atom you do

```
select iliketheschaps, resi 200‐221 and name CA+CB
color tv_green, iliketheschaps
show spheres, iliketheschaps
```

The object `iliketheschaps` is a selection. Do make sure the range is a hyphen-minus (character next to 0) as opposed to an en-dash (–) which Word subs and on a mac you get with <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>

### non-PyMOL colours

Now you asked for "gold". This is not a colour in the menu —famous for the colour `limon`. Gold is a CSS colour name, but it won't work.
You will have to colour by hex code. Say you want "gold" you need to google the colour name and hex. #FFD700.

```
color 0xFFD700, iliketheschaps
```

### The Fashion Police have been alerted

> This paragraph is in jest.

However, as you may know bioinformaticians are very fashion savvy for colours. Mustard was the in-colour from last year, so you really ought to use mustard (`0xffdb58`). This year is all about nectarine (`0xffa168`) (which is not salmon —this ain't 2015!). Coral (`0xff7f50`) and teal (`0x008080`) were from previous years and are still are going strong!

Answer (score -1):

show sphere, A/1/C

set sphere_color, red, A/1/C

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer, and format code lines better. As it stands, this post is low quality and might be deleted.